# Test QueryParams with Spock and Java Spark

Tags: java, testing, spock, spark-java

I am working with Java Spark and Groovy Spock for testing. I am currently trying to test queryParams from an URI but i can't seem to figure it out.

Actually i have a few tests working for testing path params like this:

```
import spark.Request
import spark.routematch.RouteMatch
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class ChargeRouterValidatorSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = Mock(HttpServletRequest.class)
    @Shared
    Request request

    void "test"() {
        given:
        RouteMatch match = new RouteMatch(null, "/charges/:id", "/charges/1" , "text/html")
        request = new Request(match, servletRequest)

        when:
        def test = request.params("id")

        then:
        test == "1"
    }
}
```

Spark Request uses changeMatch method which splits the first URI string from RouteMatch in '/' as well as the second URI string, compares and gets params which match the position of split parts that begin with ':'

That works perfect and test evaluates to 1.

Now, when i try to test queryParams

```
import spark.Request
import spark.routematch.RouteMatch
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class ChargeRouterValidatorSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = Mock(HttpServletRequest.class)
    @Shared
    Request request

    void "test"() {
        given:
        RouteMatch match = new RouteMatch(null, "/charges/:id", "/charges/1?test=test" , "text/html")
        request = new Request(match, servletRequest)

        when:
        def test = request.queryParams("test")

        then:
        test == "test"
    }
}
```

Test is always null.

My question is how should i correctly test for queryParams?

I want to add that when i run locally and try it, queryParams evaluates correctly but i can't make tests depending on a server.

Comment: Welcome to SO! :-) This question is about [Spark-Java](http://sparkjava.com/), not about Apache Spark. I have fixed your false question tag. Maybe now you are going to get an answer. Two more things: (1) Please change your question into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With imports cut off from your snippets one can only guess which framework you are using. (2) This is definitely not a testing or Spock question, you are clearly asking questions about the Spark-Java API.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for the tips, i have edited it showing the imports. As for (2), i know it's not Spock directly but letting people know i'm on it, maybe they can come up with a 'Spock oriented' solution

Comment: @SebastianKondek - if queryParams evaluates correctly locally it means that the test functionality is OK. Did you try to print and play with `request.contextPath()` and `request.host()` to see the differences between testing locally and remotely?

Comment: @SHG Thanks for the comment. I have found a workaround. As for your question, i did try and those two are null when running the tests remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. Spock has a similar function to Mockito when().thenReturn() which is mock.method(param) >> wantedResult

So the test looks like this:

```
import spark.Request
import spark.routematch.RouteMatch
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class ChargeRouterValidatorSpec extends Specification {
@Shared
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = Mock(HttpServletRequest.class)
@Shared
Request request

void "test"() {
    given:
    RouteMatch match = new RouteMatch(null, "/charges/:id", "/charges/1" , "text/html")
    request = new Request(match, servletRequest)

    when:
    servletRequest.getParameter("test") >> "test"
    def test = request.queryParams("test")

    then:
    test == "test"
}
}
```

This evaluates correctly.

Comment: What kind of test is that supposed to be? You are successfully testing that your mock returns a mock result. Earlier you said you wanted to test the case `"/charges/1?test=test"`, which is not what you do in your code here. In reality, as you already noticed, Spark-Java does not return the result you expect. So IMO you are fooling yourself into believing your application does what it should by tweaking an irrelevant test to pass. Maybe you want to re-investigate and re-analyse a bit?

Comment: @kriegaex Actually its the same, because in the case `"/charges/1?test=test"` i am expecting Spark to handle test queryParam which he does by `servletRequest.getParameter()`. In the first example, as SHG said in the comments, `request.ContextPath()` and `request.host()`are both null so i believe is for that reason that mu URI is not being evaluated. By mocking the answer of the method that the URI will use in normal situations and returning the value that is supposed to be sent in the test case `"/charges/1?test=test"` seems correct to me.

Comment: @kriegaex Also, this is just a simple scenario. The actual scenario is also tested in stage servers, where `request.ContextPath()` and `request.host()` are not null and Spark can handle queryParams correctly within the URI

Comment: Sorry, but your test as posted here, fails. There is no good reason for you to use `@Shared` anyway, so I just removed the annotations. Only then it passes.

Answer (score 1):

I sustain my criticism of your test. It is meaningless because you are just testing that method `Request.queryParams(String)` returns the value you define to be returned by your mock or stub. Furthermore, you create the `Request` using a package-protected constructor, which only works because you are using Groovy. Here is the relevant part of the class under test:

```java
package spark;

// (...)

public class Request {

  // (...)

  private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

  // (...)

  Request(RouteMatch match, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.servletRequest = request;
    changeMatch(match);
  }

  public String queryParams(String queryParam) {
    return servletRequest.getParameter(queryParam);
  }

  // (...)
}
```

See? You are just testing that the mock can return a mock result. And why are you unit-testing a third-party class anyway? This makes no sense whatsoever, unless your sample code is not your real test but just s small part of a bigger test and you are actually testing something else (one of your own classes) and just need the mock result for something else. But as given, the test is just nonsense.

Anyway, for what it is worth, a few hints about your test structure:

- Why use `@Shared`? The beauty of Spock is that instance variables are not shared by default so as to avoid side effects and dependencies between tests. Even worse, the code in your own, accepted solution fails unless you remove `@Shared` altogether. I tried. You should be more cautious about posting answers to your own questions which do not even work and then even accepting them.
- You have two test cases, but only posted an answer for one of them, but not even the one you had problems with before.
- The two test cases are also very similar in structure, the only thing which is different is the request URI for the `RouteMatch`. I suggest you use a parametrised test with `where:` and `@Unroll` for this case. It gets rid of duplicate code and with a few renames for the test and variable names is more readable.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spark.Request
import spark.routematch.RouteMatch
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

class SparkJavaTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll
  def "Request returns expected value for query parameter '#requestUri'"() {
    given:
    def routeMatch = new RouteMatch(null, "/charges/:id", requestUri, "text/html")
    def servletRequest = Stub(HttpServletRequest) {
      getParameter("test") >> "test"
    }
    def request = new Request(routeMatch, servletRequest)

    expect:
    request.queryParams("test") == "test"

    where:
    requestUri << ["/charges/1", "/charges/1?test=test"]
  }
}
```

BTW, whether you use `Mock()` or `Stub()` in the example above, is up to you.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. Now, i might have forgotten to write it, but yea, this is a test case made to better reflect my problem. The test is actually of a larger scope in which i'm testing my own method, which does some validations on the request received. 
Some of those validations are checking for queryParams, which i was failing to test because Spark wouldn't handle the request correctly out of a server context.
Why use `@Shared`? As i said above, this is a larger context so this is not the only test case in which i need `Request`and `HttpServlerRequest` that's why i use it as

Comment: a shared resource.
I have two test cases. if i understood correctly, i have two examples. First one showing that `Spark.params()`works correctly, and the second one (my problem) showing that `Spark.queryParams()`fails on my test.
I am still unfamiliar with spock so i appreciate the last tip.
Also, the solution i provided, compiles and runs perfectly on my project.

Comment: I can hardly believe that, I really checked. Anyway, don't use `@Shared`. Creating a mock is cheap and assigning a value to another variable in a test you do anyway. You save no time but bleed context into another feature method. It is just not worth the risk because there is no gain. You want to avoid interdependencies and side effects between methods. Believe me, I have a wee bit of experience in testing. Go for clean code.

Comment: thanks for the tips, i will be looking into it and and refactor